# Access unpromoted snapshot

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob that I have taken a snapshot of.  The original blob is then modified and I would like to get the old data off of the snapshot.

How can I achieve this without promoting the snapshot, or creating a new blob based on my snapshot?

Thanks for any information

More specifics:

I have a virtual machine with a mounted blob data disk.  I take a snapshot of that blob.  I then change two files on the virtual machine: foo.jpg, goo.png.

I would like to directly extract the previous versions of foo.jpg and goo.png from the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the following code as an example:

```
static void ReferenceBlobSnapshot(CloudBlobClient blobClient)
{
    //Get a reference to a blob.
    CloudBlob blob = blobClient.GetBlobReference("mycontainer/myblob.txt");

    //Take a snapshot of the blob.
    CloudBlob snapshot = blob.CreateSnapshot();

    //Get the snapshot timestamp.
    DateTime timestamp = (DateTime)snapshot.Attributes.Snapshot;

    //Use the timestamp to get a second reference to the snapshot.
    CloudBlob snapshot2 = new CloudBlob("mycontainer/myblob.txt", timestamp, blobClient);

    //Write out the snapshot URI and timestamp.
    Console.WriteLine(snapshot2.Uri);
    Console.WriteLine(snapshot2.SnapshotTime);
}
```

Remember the snapshot is a blob too.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, Brian.  I added a few more details of the specific issue I'm trying to solve.